# Checking if a button is disabled or not

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

my issue i am having is that selenium is saying that the **next arrow button** is enabled when it is disabled/grayed out. what i am trying to do is this

1 click next arrow button
2 sleep for 5 seconds
3 check if disabled
4 click next arrow button
5 check if disabled
( loop repeat steps 1 -5)
 if button is disabled break do while loop

my code that is not working is below

```
 PS_OBJ_CycleData.Nextbtn(driver).click();
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("changeStartWeekGrid_next"));
 if (element.isEnabled()) {
  System.out.println("Good next arrow enabled");
 } else {
  System.out.println("next arrow disabled");
  PS_OBJ_CycleData.Cancelbtn(driver).click();
  break dowhileloop;
 }
```

my console output is "Good next arrow enabled" instead of going to the else statment.

Button HTML is here

```
<div id="changeStartWeekGrid_next" class="paginationButton" disabled="disabled" data-xpal="xpath-selected">
   <a tabindex="0" href="#" id="changeStartWeekGrid_next_link" onclick="var registry = require('dijit/registry'); registry.byId('changeStartWeekGrid').next(); return false;">
   <span class="icon-pagination-next"></span>
   </a>
</div>
```

As you can see the button is actually disabled there another way to check is button is really disabled? Any help would be appreciated.

this is an additional picture of the inspected element
[image]

Comment: But that's not a button. That's a div masquerading as a button.

Comment: I posted an addition picture above for you that all i have when i inspect the element.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you don't believe me. That is not a button. It doesn't matter if you *think* it is.

Comment: If there any way to check the html code to see if the attribute is disabled? and if so break the loop?

Comment: I believe you i just done know where to go from here when i inspect the element that what i get i can click on it an and the arrow shows the next page till its grayed out

Comment: is there a way to check the pagination button state and if it is disabled do something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation for isEnabled](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html#isEnabled--).

Sadly, using the isEnabled method doesn't work in this case, as stated by the documentation:

> This will generally return true for everything but disabled **input** elements.

A proper alternative is using JavaScript to check for the attribute's existence, and its value. You can inject JavaScript through the [executeScript](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method of the webdriver classes. The first argument is the script, all following arguments are passed to the script, accessible as arguments[i], ...

For example:

```
Boolean disabled = driver.executeScript("return arguments[0].hasAttribute(\"disabled\");", element);
```

Comment: yous there is a proper alternative in javaScript can this solution be used in java if so how can i modify my code so it will work?

Comment: is there any way to check the html code to see if the attribute is disabled? and if so break the loop?

Comment: I extended my answer.

Comment: My solution was this  if (driver.findElement(By.id("changeStartWeekGrid_next")).getAttribute("disabled") != null) {
                     PS_OBJ_CycleData.Cancelbtn(driver).click();
               break dowhileloop;
                     }

Answer (score 0):

I In this case since i did not have an actual button I needed to find it attribute to see if it was disabled or not.

```
  PS_OBJ_CycleData.Nextbtn(driver).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    // check is arrow button is disabled
    if (driver.findElement(By.id("changeStartWeekGrid_next")).getAttribute("disabled") != null) {
     PS_OBJ_CycleData.Cancelbtn(driver).click();
     break dowhileloop;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with this simple code:

```
Boolean isbutton;
isbutton=button1.isEnable()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct element. I've wasted hours trying to figure out why an element was enabled when it shouldn't have been, when I was actually looking at the wrong one! Inspecting the element in the browser did not help, because it wasn't the same element that the java code was looking at. The following code turned out to be helpful:

```
System.out.println("Actual element=" + describeElement(yourElement));

public static String describeElement(WebElement element) {
    String result = "";
    if (element == null ) {
        log.error("Could not describe null Element");
        return "null";
    } 
    // Look for common attributes, such as id, name, value, title, placeholder, type,  href, target, role, class,
    String id = element.getAttribute("id");
    String name = element.getAttribute("name");
    String value = element.getAttribute("value");
    String title = element.getAttribute("title");
    String placeholder = element.getAttribute("placeholder");
    String type = element.getAttribute("type");
    String href = element.getAttribute("href");
    String target = element.getAttribute("target");
    String role = element.getAttribute("role");
    String thisClass = element.getAttribute("class");

    result = "WebElement [tag:" + element.getTagName() + " text:'" + limit(element.getText()) + "' id:'" + id + "' " +
            (StringUtils.isEmpty(name) ? "" : (" name:'" + name + "' ")) + 
            (StringUtils.isEmpty(name) ? "" : (" value:'" + value + "' ")) + 
            (StringUtils.isEmpty(name) ? "" : (" title:'" + title + "' ")) + 
            (StringUtils.isEmpty(name) ? "" : (" placeholder:'" + placeholder + "' ")) + 
            (StringUtils.isEmpty(name) ? "" : (" type:'" + type + "' ")) + 
            (StringUtils.isEmpty(name) ? "" : (" href:'" + href + "' ")) + 
            (StringUtils.isEmpty(name) ? "" : (" target:'" + target + "' ")) + 
            (StringUtils.isEmpty(name) ? "" : (" name:'" + name + "' ")) + 
            (StringUtils.isEmpty(name) ? "" : (" role:'" + role + "' ")) + 
            (StringUtils.isEmpty(name) ? "" : (" class:'" + thisClass + "' ")) + 
            " isDisplayed: " + element.isDisplayed() +
            " isEnabled: " + element.isEnabled() +
            " isSelected: " + element.isSelected() + "]";
    return result;
}
```

Comment: your solution doesn't work. you should use javascript executor.